# Need Hint; Show that the Limit Exists when $f\in C^1(0,1)$ and...

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

The problem is as follows:

> Assume that $f\in C^1(0,1)$ and
>   $$
> \int_{(0,1)}x|f'|^p\,dx<+\infty\qquad\text{for some }p>2.
> $$
>   Show that $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}f(x)$ exists.

Note: $C^1(0,1)$ is the space of continuously differentiable functions on $(0,1)$.

What I've considered so far;

- I know that $x\in C^1(0,1)$.
- I know that $f$ is differentiable.
- I know that the definition of the right-hand limit here will be important (which I have written down on my scratch work).

However, I am having difficulty in figuring out where to continue off from here. I think I might be missing some important Theorem.

Comment: When you say $C^1$, you mean the space of continuously *differentiable* functions right?

Comment: @rubikscube09 Yes. That is a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: It is not clear that $f'\in L^p$. For example, you could have $f'=x^{-1/p}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find that for $0<x<y<1$,
$$\begin{align*}
|f(x)-f(y)| &\le\int_x^y |f'(t)|\mathrm dt\\
&\le\left(\int_x^y t|f'(t)|^p\mathrm dt\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_x^y t^{\frac1{1-p}}\mathrm dt\right)^{1-1/p}\\
&\le \left(\int_0^1 t|f'(t)|^p\mathrm dt\right)^{1/p}\left(\frac{p-1}{p-2}\cdot\left(y^{\frac{p-2}{p-1}}-x^{\frac{p-2}{p-1}}\right)\right)^{1-1/p}
\end{align*}$$ by Holder's inequality, which implies that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$. Hence, $f$ can be continuously extended to $[0,1]$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$ exists.

Comment: AHH, the good old Continuous Extension Theorem. I really need to take some good notes on that.